# Large ASP MVC @Html.DropDownListFor not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, firefox

I am Using ASP MVC  Dropdownlist for cities on my website

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CityId, ViewBag.CityDataBag as SelectList, new { id = "citydropdown", style = "height:33px;font-size: small", @class = "ui fluid search dropdown" })
```

[image]

When Users trying to choose city From dropdown in Firefox Browser.Combobox not working page just not responding.

1. On my Windows 8 and Firefox latest version everything works fine..
2. When I load small amount of cities dropdown works and page dont breaks..
3. on first load ViewBag Contains about 3000+ city items.
4. Binding Works Problem is occuring just when you click

Can't Figure Out Why Some users have problems with firefox Browser  when others 
 don't.

Any Idea?

Comment: Have you tried validating the HTML on the page? You might have something unexpected in the drop down causing issues for the parser.

Comment: TBH,3000 items in a dropdown is too much unless you have a searchable dropdown

Comment: As @Locke125 pointed out - there are plenty of cities with `'` apostrophe in the name which the html *may* not be handling correctly.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899510/american-cities-with-special-characters-in-the-name

Comment: that is certainly a lot of data, do you expect user to search through all of it ? are you using any plugin ?

Comment: I dont have any other choise i must load such big data ..

Comment: _I don't have any other choice_ - of course you do. You cannot expect your users to scroll through 3000+ items. Use a jquery autocomplete plugin (that makes an ajax call to display only the cities based on the first character they type, or use cascading dropdownlists to categorize your options.

Answer (score 0):

3000 is a lot of data, what I would do is pass my viewbag to the view, serialize it as json object (it will be array of [key value pair](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx), where key is the city name and value is the city id), and do search on the fly using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), I would use [dataList](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp), and I would use hidden field to keep the id of the city, when the user select the country from the options displayed. 
Here is how to achieve it

```
<input type="text" id="mytextbox" list="citiesDataList" placeholder="e.g. datalist">
<input type="hidden" id="CityId" name="CityId" />
<datalist id="citiesDataList"></datalist>
```

in your js

```
// here we have json object of the list of cities , serialized 
var jsonOptions = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.CityDataBag));
// on change listener, filter the list, update the datalist according to the filtered list      
$("#mytextbox").on("change", function(){
// if the length is more than to reduce the result only 
if(this.value.length > 1){
// empty datalist 
$("#citiesDataList").html("");
//filter cities based on user input 
     var cities = jsonOptions.filter(function(city){
      // return cities that the name of it contains the value of the text box
      return city.Key.indexOf(this.value) > -1;
});
// if only one result, we assume user already selected the city he wants
if(cities.length === 1)
{
// so we pass the id that matches the filter, get the first result from filter function, then pass its id to the hidden field.
$("#CityId").val(cities[0].Value);
}
// if more than one, update datalist accordingly 
else
{
//loop through the result, all cities that contains the characters inserted
cities.forEach(function(city) {
            // Create a new <option> element.
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            // Set the value using the city in the JSON array, city is an object, I assume Name field is the name of the city
            option.value = city.Key;
            // Add the <option> element to the citiesDataList.
            $("#citiesDataList").append(option);
          });
//end of else
}
//end of value.length > 1
}
//end of the listener 
});
```

**Note if there are duplicate cities name with different ids, this won't work as expected, this is expecting city name to be unique.**

Comment: How come one city have more than one id ? that is bad data. 
how it is different then, lets say city 1 id 1 and city 1 id 2 ? doesn't make sense right ?

Comment: after some research i fount that if Print/Print Preview add on  in firefox instaled my combobox workss...

Comment: i used jquery autocompletedropdown it solved problem!